# Python for loop and save to .csv file

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a question using 'for' loop

I'm not in English-speaking countries so my english skills are bad so understand my situation

This code calculates R_list in response to lambda_list by substituting each item of d_list into each lambda_list.

original code is

```py
d_list = [inf,80, 10, 80,100,inf] #in nm
lambda_list = linspace(350,821,471) #in nm
R_list = []
for lambda_vac in lambda_list:
    n_list = [1, Si02_n_fn(lambda_vac), Cr_nk_fn(lambda_vac), Si02_n_fn(lambda_vac), Al_nk_fn(lambda_vac), 1.5]
    R_list.append(coh_tmm('p',n_list,d_list,0,lambda_vac)['R'])
```

i want to get large dataset so i have to change d_list parameters in person.
but it takes a long time to change parameters one by one.

so i add 'for loop' in Original code:

```py
for i in range(0, 11):
    d_list = [inf,70+i,5,90,100,inf] #in nm
    lambda_list = linspace(350,821,471) #in nm
    R_list = []    
    for lambda_vac in lambda_list:
        n_list = [1, Si02_n_fn(lambda_vac), Cr_nk_fn(lambda_vac), Si02_n_fn(lambda_vac), Al_nk_fn(lambda_vac), 1.5]
        R_list.append(coh_tmm('p',n_list,d_list,0,lambda_vac)['R'])

        df = pd.DataFrame(R_list, columns = ['R_list'])

        df.transpose()

        if not os.path.exists('Reflectivity.csv'):
            df.transpose().to_csv('Reflectivity.csv', index=False, mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
        else:
            df.transpose().to_csv('Reflectivity.csv', index=False, mode='a', encoding='utf-8', header=False)
```

but it has a problem in save to .csv file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdYOD.png)

The original result is at the top.

and using 'for loop' result is like stair

what should I change the code?

FYI : save to .csv file code is:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(R_list, columns = ['R_list'])

df.transpose()

if not os.path.exists('Reflectivity.csv'):
    df.transpose().to_csv('Reflectivity.csv', index=False, mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
else:
    df.transpose().to_csv('Reflectivity.csv', index=False, mode='a', encoding='utf-8', header=False)
```

thank you for reading!

Comment: Please always properly indent your code before posting.

Comment: Hii @OP, you have not added your code properly as well as, I can not figure if you have written the logic to save in .csv file inside the for loop or outside, but after analysing the code I assume that it must be inside when you are appending the data inside R_list. So you are saving the R_list while it is being created and the data is appending. So it might be possible that your output is faulty because of writing R_list in every iteration.

Comment: sorry i edit the code